# Difficulty in partitioning after installation

Tags: partitioning, drive

I have installed Ubuntu12. While installing I haven't created any Partition. I am trying to create one now, but it not allowing me to do that, saying, 'The device is busy'. Please help.

Comment: Note: you can't do resize operation on a mounted partition. So try to unmount it. And also you can't unmount UBuntu partition(`/`). For this you have to boot from live disk. Add some extra details on your question by posting the screenshot of your gparted partition editor or by posting the output of `sudo blkid` command.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Ubuntu? Also, is it Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10? It probably isn't a big deal, but it could be.

Assuming you booted from your hard drive, you're in luck - you have already made a partition, perhaps without knowing it. If instead you meant that you wanted to make multiple partitions here's how:

1. Live boot into your system, the same way as when you first installed (disk or flash drive)
2. Open a terminal
3. Type ´ sudo gparted´
4. Look for your hard drive in 'devices' on the right. It's likely to be /dev/sdb but maybe not, so watch out.
5. Make sure the device's pprtitions are unmounted (right click them and if it says unmount, do it)
6. Your hard drive us likely set up with one large partition and one swap partition. For the purposes of this, wipe out the swap partition (look for the delete/remove button)
7. Right click your main partion and click 'move/resize'
8. Resize your partition to how big you want it to be. Warning: shirt from the RIGHT not the LEFT as doing this could ruin your bootloader
9. Select the area now known as 'unallocated slave's right click, and click to create a new partition. Make this partition however large you want it to be.
10. Repeat above u til you're satisfied
11. Click the green check mark